# How to add static column(s) in jQuery DataTables

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.10.7. I have binded few columns. In that few columns are static and few are dynamic.

So currently I have binded around 20 columns (static + dynamic) in DataTable. Now, I have binded till to 20 cols now suppose if I am binding 21 cols it's gives me error like

> DataTables warning: table id=DataGrid - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Please attached screenshots. In first snapshot it's working till on hand columns and next screenshots will display error while I am binding next column of OnHand.

I have set this part too in my DataTable.

```
"aoColumns": [
   { sWidth: '1%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' },
   { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' },
   { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' },
   { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }
 ],
```

[image]
[image]

**Here my code like this**

```
function OnddlRegionRankGroupChange(val) {

  var Tblheader = '';
  var trHTML = '';

  Re_Bind_DataTable();
  $("#DataGrid").empty()

  Tblheader = '<thead><tr><th rowspan="2" style="width: 5%;">Excl.</th><th rowspan="2">CUC</th> <th rowspan="2"> Late Model </th><th colspan="2">' + '1 Year Rank </th><th colspan="2"> 1 Year Sales Qty </th> <th rowspan="2"> Whse Looksup </th><th colspan="12" align="center"> Qty of Parts Sold by Mo.' +
     '</th> <th rowspan="2"> Days OOS </th> <th rowspan="2"> On Hand </th> <th colspan="4" align="center"> Re-Order High </th> <%--<th> &nbsp; </th>--%> ' +
     '</tr> <tr> <th> Whse </th> <th> Region </th><th> Whse </th> <th>Region</th><th> 12 </th> <th>11</th> <%--<th> .... </th>--%> <th class="cellhidden"> ' +
     '10 </th> <th class="cellhidden">9 </th> <th class="cellhidden"> 8 </th> <th class="cellhidden"> 7  </th> <th class="cellhidden"> 6 </th>' +
     '<th class="cellhidden"> 5 </th>  <th class="cellhidden">4 </th> <th> 3</th>  <th>2 </th> <th> 1  </th> <th> Current </th> <th> Diff </th> <th>' +
     ' Recomd </th> <th> Last </th> <%--<th>  &nbsp; </th>--%>   </tr> </thead>';

  $("#DataGrid").append(Tblheader);

  $('#DataGrid').DataTable({
     "iDisplayLength": 25,
     "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
     "bServerSide": true,
     "bProcessing": false,
     "bPaginate": true,
     "sDom": 'fltip',
     "bDeferRender": true,
     "sAjaxSource": '<%= Url.Action("GetTest") %>',
     "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push({ "name": "WhseID", "value": $("#ddlWarehouse").val() },
                    { "name": "strCatg", "value": $("#ddlCategory").val() })
     },
     "aoColumns": [
        { sWidth: '1%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' },
        { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' },
        { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' },
        { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }, { sWidth: '5%' }
     ],      
     "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {
        setTimeout(function () { $.loader('close'); }, 1000);
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: we need more information from you. is this error triggered by your ajax call?

Comment: And please show us how you bind your data to the DT

Comment: Show how you are adding dynamic columns and are you re-initializing dataTable?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my question. Now you can please check.

Comment: Please post your JSON response as recommended by the link http://datatables.net/tn/1 in the error mesage, it will be clear why "Invalid JSON response" is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got answer of my question.
Actually, My problem was I had bind till 20 cols(including static and dynamic). Till 20 cols it was working very well. But once I go ahead and try to add one more col(21th cols) at that time, I was facing issue.

**Solution is**
Just need to set below line in DataTable config setting

**"sServerMethod": "POST",**

e.g

```
 $("#DataGrid").DataTable({
                        "iDisplayLength": 10,
                        "bServerSide": true,
                        "sDom": 'fltip',
                        "sAjaxSource": '<%= Url.Action("GetTest") %>',
                        *"sServerMethod": "POST"*
})
```

Because Post Method storing capacity of response is better than GET Response. Get Method having limitation of storing response.